# use gedit to open file with null characters

Tags: linux, character-encoding, gedit

I know GEdit has a bug which prevents it from opening a file with null (`\0`) characters in it. This is a huge inconvenience for me because I frequently have to open big log files with only a couple rogue `\0`'s in them.

Sometimes I just run a quick `tr -d '\0' < file.log > file.log.correct` and open the correct file. This is a big nuisance. I would like to have maybe an external tool in GEdit that would execute the above command. I tried writing an external tool action (GEdit plugin) using just:

```
#!/bin/bash
tr -d '\0'
```

Input is "current document", output action is "replace current document". But this isn't working. When I open the file, GEdit shows the familiar red warning; activating the external tool with the warning showing apparently has no effect (I think the script is being called but its input/output are not set).

Any other ideas I could try?

Comment: use a real editor *cough* vim *cough* :)

Comment: I thought of that, but this tool does (mostly) all I need it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that works on a document that's already loaded rather than one that's in the process of being loaded.

You could use a wrapper script or function that does the `tr` for you then launches `gedit`.

Comment: Fair enough, this is what I ended up doing. Since I am used to navigating to a folder and double-clicking a file to open in GEdit, I created a Nautilus custom action. Now I have a menu item "Remove Null Characters" in my right-click context menu, that I can invoke before viewing the file.